# Instance lifetime management

Tags: autofac, caliburn.micro

I am using `Caliburn.Micro v2` along with `Autofac` and I am having some issues with the `WindowManager.ShowDialog` function.

I have the following which successfully displays a `dialog`:

```
windowManager.ShowDialog(dialogViewModel.Show(typeToShow));
```

If after closing the newly shown window via the `cross` button I recall the above expecting to see the `dialog` once again, I encounter the following exception:

> Cannot set Visibility or call Show, ShowDialog, or WindowInteropHelper.EnsureHandle after a Window has closed.

It is my understanding that the error is due to `ShowDialog` only being usable once and that if I want to call `ShowDialog` again, I need to provide a new instance.  I have proven this to some degree by using:

```
windowManager.ShowDialog(new DialogViewModel().Show(typeToShow));
```

This successfully results in a new `dialog` each time, however, I do not wish to call `new` here each time.  How do I therefore tell `Autofac` to give me a new instance of `DialogViewModel` each time, rather than reusing the same instance?

**EDIT 1 - DialogViewModel registration**

```
var buider = new ContainerBuilder();
builder.Register(e => new DialogViewModel())
       .AsSelf()
       .InstancePerDependency();
```

I have previously been using `.SingleInstance()` and thought using `.InstancePerDependency()` might be what I was looking for, it appears not though.

Comment: How do you register your dialogViewModel in the container?

Comment: @nemesv - OP edited to include VM container registration.

Answer (score 1):

Autofac has built-in factory support via `Func<T>` class. You just need to resolve `Func<DialogViewModel>` instead of `DialogViewModel` which means a factory that returns `DialogViewModel`. You don't need to change your existing registration. More info on [wiki page.](https://github.com/autofac/Autofac/wiki/Relationship-Types)